# Is there a correspondence between docker and docker compose versions?

Tags: docker

Nowadays, when installing docker, the docker compose command is installed by default, is there any correspondence between the versions of docker and docker compose?

Comment: `docker-compose` is no longer a separate command; it is now a subcommand of `docker` itself.  So of course they are the same version, because you are talking about only a single command `docker` which must be the same version as itself.